# Android: Javascript function not continuing after eval()

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am trying to execute an arbitrary Javascript function on an Android WebView and get its result.  To invoke the function, I use loadUrl() and I have also added a Javascript interface that is supposed to be called with the result.  This is what the JS looks like that I am trying to execute from loadUrl():

```
(function () {
  var res = eval(foo());
  MyInterface.setResult(res); 
})()
```

`foo` stands in for the name of the function I am trying to invoke and `MyInterface` is the interface that I added earlier.  When I do this, `foo()` does get invoked but the next call does not.  I tried changing `MyInterface.setResult(res);` to simpler JS statements like `console.log("finished")` but nothing is executed after `eval()`.  If I remove `eval` the next statement is executed.  Any idea on what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eval takes a string. It's trying to invoke a string foo is returning.

Try eval("foo()");

edit: you could just call the function without eval as well.

Comment: Damn. This seems incredibly obvious in retrospect!  Thank you very much :)